# iDRAC8 cannot sent emails; Settings configured

Tags: dell

Ive updated the iDRAC 8 I have on a Dell PowerEdge R730 but when I try to send alert emails from it, it fails.

The message is (rough translation):

RAC0225: Failed test of sending email.

Really tells me nothing

I Wiresharked the conversation

http://pastebin.com/p1DmLzhN

Can't see anything that catches my eye that could be throwing this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ideally you'd look at the logs on the SMTP server but I assume you don't have access to them. Possible cause might be the hostname used in the HELO/EHLO - some sites object to hostnames ending in .local or unknown TLDs. Can you change the iDRAC's idea of its hostname?

Comment: Right now it is: idrac-servicetaghere.myactivedirectorydomain.local Do you have any suggestions on what I should change it to? I really have no preference/care as long as it fixes it.

Comment: I'd suggest changing it to something as close as possible to the real FQDN that the external mail server will see. There's some discussion of similr problems at http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/177/t/19484401 .  If I was doing this, my inclination would be to run a small SMTP relay server on-site, configure the iDRAC to send to that (which makes diagnosis of connection problems easier) and then route onwards from there,

Comment: I imagine by the real FQDN that the external mail server will see is what is resolved by DNS for my public IP right? Difficult to achive as Im using a external DNS server to resolve my public IP and not sure how exactly to configure that. My public IP resolves to local.mydomain.com Should I make it idrac.mydomain.com and then add in my external DNS server a entry for idrac.mydomain.com?

Comment: Some clarification is needed so I can adjust this.

Comment: You could try just using the FQDN corresponding to your external address. The main problem in diagnosing this is that all you're getting back from the iDRAC is success/failure, you don't have access to the logs on the SMTP server you're using and you can't see the details of the SMTP conversation because that's encrypted. You're left with changing stuff until it works :-<. Alternative approaches would be to use SWAKS or similar to test sending with yout parameters _or_ running a local SMTP server.

Comment: When you mention my "external address" what exactly are you talking about? The external address on my WAN/public IP for my network? And where exactly does that go?

Answer (score 2):

This is dumb, but it worked for me.

Following the steps in this site: https://techstat.net/how-to-setup-simple-smtp-alerts-for-dells-idrac/

Under iDRAC>Network in the DNS section, you put username from the mail you want to use to send mails from, further down you put the domain.

Then under the SMTP settings you use this same username to authenticate to the mail server.

Comment: BTW: Works with Office 365, but be sure that the DNS username and domain name are listed as a "send as" alias of the Office 365 credentials supplied.

Answer (score 0):

After a through attempts
i have got through this issue.
Finally resolved

I Was using gmail server for triggering emails.

as per all the solution experts i have tried defining a domain name then DNS etc.

Finally i have changed smtp server port number from 465 to 25.

this have worked for me..
hope this could be a solution for other also.

pl try..
bye

Answer (score 0):

First check the DNS servers on `Settings>Network`, it should be

If it continues giving you one error the problem should be the iDrac it's using for the from field of each email the conjunction of the DNS Name and the domain we can set on iDRAC `Settings>Network>DNS DRAC Name` and `Settings>Network>Static DNS Domain Name`

That generates one error like this in the SMTP server which usually discards the email

> 2018-03-05 11:53:45 H=xxxxx (xxxxxx) [xxxx]:47507 sender verify fail
>   for : The mail server could not deliver mail to
>   iDRACSrv1_dns@domain.  The account or domain may not exist, they may
>   be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries.

So the solution it's to use on the `DNS DRAC Name` field the name of one email account (the part before the @), and on the field `Static DNS Domain Name` the domain a that email account (the part after the @). The resulting account should be *DNS_DRAC_Name@Static_DNS_Domain_Name*